# Magento 2.4.5 For Out of stock products Breadcrumbs full path is not showing

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.5, breadcrumbs, pdp

For Out of stock products Breadcrumbs full path is not showing when I visit from the category page. Help me out on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ful path is only visible when you visit product from category page. If you visit product directly there is no full breadcrumbs path.

Comment: #anže-voh I visited the out of stock product from the category page to product page so the breadcrumb full path is not shown but for in-stock it is showing. @anže-voh